# Azure KeyVault: How to tell if a key is HSM protected

Tags: azure, powershell, security, azure-keyvault

I have a key vault that I created and imported a key several months ago. I created the vault with a [SKU of premium](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/key-vault-get-started/) as per the documentation to enable Key Vault's usage of an HSM.  I also imported the key setting the destination = to HSM

```
Add-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName 'ContosoKeyVaultHSM' -Name 'ContosoFirstHSMKey' -Destination 'HSM'
```

Now, I am being asked to verify that the key is in fact hardware protected, but I'm not able to find any overly convincing attribute to tell me this.  If I run: 
`Get-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName "Contoso" -KeyName "ITPfx"`

I can see in the JSON "kty: RSA-HSM" where a software protected key's kty value is just RSA.  That is the only difference I can see between a hardware and software protected key.

Is that really the only way to tell if a key is in the HSM in the key vault?

Or is there a more intuitive method to determine this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using PowerShell, this is the code I use to identify if weather the key is protected by software or hsm:

```
$keyInVault = Get-AzureKeyVaultKey -VaultName $keyVaultName -Name $keyName
$keyInVault.Key.Kty
```

The output will look something like:

> RSA-HSM

So, yes using the JSON is typically the only way.

Comment: I came to the same conclusion, is there documentation somewhere that states the way we mentioned is the typically the only way?